# Add an item to PouchDB document property from type array

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I have a document which has an array property.
How to append a new item to this property?
Is there a function similar to MongoDB's `$push()`?

The only resolution I found to this problem is to reassign the property with a new one which contains all of the old values plus the new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PouchDB has no concept of "append". To update a document, you must completely replace it.

Once you've fetched a document from PouchDB, you can modify it however you want, using JavaScript's `push()` method, or any other modification technique, but then you must write the entire document to PouchDB at once, to update it.